# Why does the following Integer type variable output -1?

Tags: vba, integer

```
Sub Test()
    Dim iX As Integer

    iX = 1 = 1

    'Out put is -1
    MsgBox iX 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you compare `1` with a `1` this is `True` so `1 = 1` is `True` and `True` is considered as `-1` in VBA by definition and you write this result into your variable `iX`.

This `iX = 1 = 1` is evaluated the same as `iX = (1 = 1)` and this is `iX = True` and since `iX` is `Integer` the `True` is converted into a numeric value `-1`.

By definition in VBA:

- `True` is `-1`
- `False` is `0`

But in Excel formulas

- `True` is `1`
- `False` is `0`